# IOS Auto layout not displaying the UILabel in multiple lines when content length is longer

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios-autolayout

I am trying to build a screen similar to twitter/instagram profile page where there is a header section and below that scrollable content.

I have a view controller which has a table view. I wanted to include a header view on top of the table cells. So i dragged and dropped a "View" just above my cell and it works fine. Now i have a label inside this header view and i want the label height and UI view height to adjust automaticlly based on the content length of the label. (If the content is a long string, the number of lines of label should automatically increase and the container view(headerview)'s height should increased based on it's content items property.

I tried to set auto layout on the table(top left right and bottom to the container view(headerview). But then the label is shown in single line, truncated at the very right corner. If i remove the bottom constraint from my constraints, the label appear in multiple lines, but the container view(headerview)'s height is not increased, thus producing an overlap of the label on top of the table below that.

I have the number of lines property set to 0 for the label.

Can anyone share some ideas how to do this ? I am using Xcode 7 and swift 2

Comment: How did you calculate the header height? It may be because the header height is not increased as the label height. Try View debug after your layout is populated. Then you may find that the label height is increased but the header height remain constant, which constraints the label height.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for what you want to accomplish. If you do not care if the header scrolls with the cells, the easiest way is to do something like this:

```
----------------
Header
  Label
TableView
----------------
```

1. You should pin your header Top,Right,Left.
2. You should pin your tableView Right,Bottom,Left.
3. You should pin Header.bottom = TableView.top.
4. You should pin your Label 4 sides to it's superview(Header).
5. Set Label numberOfLines = 0

If your header has a fixed width, the label will automatically inherit that width, and setting numberOfLines=0 (a.k.a unlimited number of lines) will make your label increase it's height. Because your label is pinned to it's superView by it's 4 sides (and the header has no fixed height), your header must increase it's height to match the label height. 
Hope it helps!!